# Getting bodyUsed of Undefined error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am very new to react-native and I have written code for login

```
payload={email:"niju1992@gmail.com",password:"helo123"};
            var Options=
            {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {'Accept': 'application/json','Content-Type': 'application/json'},
              body: payload 
            }

            fetch(Conf.API.SIGNIN, Options)
            .then((response) => 
              {
                if (response.status >= 400)
                {
                    throw new Error("Bad response from server");
                }
                return response.json();
              })
            .then((responseData) => 
            {
              //this.setState({data:responseData})
              console.log(responseData)  
            }) 
            .catch((error) => {
                  console.error("Error:"+error);
              })
            .done();
```

But Iam getting error

> index.android.bundle:19291 Error:TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'bodyUsed' of undefined

Can any one who is expert. Can anyone help?

Comment: search for `bodyUsed` in your project directory, the code you have pasted do not have that.

Comment: Where is bodyUsed being use?

Comment: I have not used bodyUsed Anywhere

Comment: I figure out that Conf.API.SIGNIN was not defined. Once I defined that URL it started working.

**Thank you all**

Answer (score 5):

Just to be explicit here, the problem was that the input URL for `fetch` had a value of `undefined`.

This can result in an exception like so:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'bodyUsed' of undefined at new Request
```

---

Make sure the first argument for `fetch` is defined!
Otherwise you'll have some cryptic errors to navigate.

Comment: +1. In my case, I had a object keeping the URL, but instead of using `foo.bar.url`, I was using `foo.url`, which doesn't exist.